# Parse string as Date in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have data that comes as string in dd/mm/yyyy format. How to parse this string to datetime in c#?

I tried DateTime.TryParse(), but it doesn't recognize the string as valid date.

Comment: What error does `DateTime.TryParse()` give?

Comment: @peer The method `TryParse` does not let you specify a format with `MM`. Only the methods with `Exact` in their names can do that.

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(yourString, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

or:

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(yourString, "dd/MM/yyyy",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out yourResult)
```

(The method `DateTime.TryParse` that you tried, *can* work if the format provider (culture info) used has this format, day/month/year, with slashes and the correct order, as its "default" date pattern. This happens for example if you use the `new CultureInfo("en-GB")`, "English (United Kingdom)".)