# How to parse string as date only, not time, without using ParseExact

Tags: .net, parsing, datetime, locale

According to [Parsing Date and Time Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/parsing-datetime) (my emphasis):

> **The string representation of a date to be parsed must include the month and at least a day or year.** The string representation of a time must include the hour and at least minutes or the AM/PM designator. However, parsing supplies default values for omitted components if possible. A missing date defaults to the current date, **a missing year defaults to the current year**, a missing day of the month defaults to the first day of the month, and a missing time defaults to midnight.

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work ideally when using other locales. For example, using `nb-NO`, my WPF DatePicker formats dates as `31.12.2017`, and I want the string `1.2` to be parsed as February 1st of the current year. However, it's interpreted as the time `01.02.00` and today's date is used instead with the parsed time. (The parsing works as desired if I write `1/2`, but I don't want to force users to use non-default separators for their locale.)

Is there any way to make use of .NET's built-in locale-aware date parsing, but force it to only parse the date, not time? (I can't use `ParseExact` because I need to support different locales; therefore, [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024126/c-sharp-parsing-dates-and-times) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19711431/parse-string-as-date-in-c-sharp) aren't helpful.)

Comment: Do you know TryParseExact has an overload that takes an array of format strings? How many different locales you need to support? By the way months are M (uppercase) while minutes are m (lowercase)

Comment: An array of formatting strings is certainly not ideal. For example, what should take precedence of `MM/dd` and `dd/MM`? Both will succeed in many cases, yet based on the user's locale, only one of them is correct.

Comment: 'using nb-NO, my WPF DatePicker  ... it's interpreted as the time 01.02.00' - The only way I can reproduce that behavior is to make a clone of `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("nb-NO")` and change its `DateTimeFormat.TimeSeparator` from **":"** to **"."**.   Is it standard in that locale to use the same symbol for the DateSeperator and TimeSeparator?  Or have you changed your region settings?

Comment: I don't think I have actively changed any system settings, though I may be wrong. But yes, both `. ` and `: ` can be used as time separators in this locale.

Comment: The potential for the same character to be used for both the DateSeparator and TimeSeparator complicates things.  The [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/datetimeparse.cs,f75289affb7e0ce3) appears to account for this possibility and interprets the string as a Date if one of the numbers entered is a four digit year.  This does not help you though.  A solution could be to retrieve the DateTimeFormatInfo.ShortDatePattern and split it.  Then you could determine if it date or month first and prepare a culture specific array for ParseExact.